# Crystal Reports shows data in wrong fields runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, report

[This is design time report preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhAnL.jpg)

[image: This is design time report preview]

[This is run time report preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zah0m.jpg)

[image: This is run time report preview]

As seen from both the preview the data shown by report design time is accurate while the run time preview shows fields with data randomly selected from the database fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supplier code data shown as label "Supplier Code : " and actual field containing the supplier code {LIFNR} was merged in a crystal report text box control as  "Supplier Code : {LIFNR}" showing "Supplier Code : 0000001980" design time.

The moment I removed the merged field {LIFNR} from the text box and shown it separately in front of the text box containing text "Supplier Code : " the report preview at run time started to show correct data.

[Corrected Run time Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzbIJ.jpg)